# Geometric proof of $QM \ge AM$

Tags: geometry, inequality, means, proof-without-words

Prove by geometric reasoning that:

$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}} \ge \frac{a + b}{2}$$

The proof should be different than one well known [from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MathematicalMeans.svg):

[image]

DISCLAIMER: I think I devised such proof (that is not published anywhere to my knowledge), but I believe it is too complex (and not that beautiful). It involves some ideas from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237390/proving-frac1c-frac1a-frac1b-in-a-geometric-context). I may post it in next few days as an answer, but I am hoping someone will offer better, more beautiful, proof by then.

Comment: The wikipedia proof is short, geometric, and very elegant. What kind of proof are you after? Are you just interested in seeing different proofs of this result?

Comment: A geometric proof is given in Nelsen's book Proofs Without Words: Exercises in Visual Thinking, Volume 1, [page 54](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kx2cjyzTIYkC&pg=PA54) (due to Sidney H. Kung, see also S. Kung, Harmonic, geometric, arithmetic, root mean inequality, The College Mathematics Journal, 21 (1990) 227 http://www.jstor.org/stable/2686892  )

Comment: Nelsen also published a geometric proof in Mathematics Magazine in 1987: http://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/proof-without-words-the-harmonic-mean-geometric-mean-arithmetic-mean-root-mean-square-ineqality

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

$\qquad\qquad 2 \left(\;\color{blue}{a}^2 + \color{red}{b}^2\;\right) \;\geq\; \left(\;\color{blue}{a}+\color{red}{b}\;\right)^2$

Answer (score 6):

How about the following solution?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

$\hspace{80pt}$[image: ![square mean diagram]

The two right triangles have common base, which is also the diameter
of the red circle. The endpoints of the black diameter are also
the foci of the ellipses, and their size is determined by the tip of the respective triangle.
Observe, that the minor radius of the blue ellipse is equal to the radius of the red circle, thus the circle is inscribed into the blue ellipse.
Therefore, as the tip of the green triangle is contained within
the blue ellipse, its perimeter has to be smaller or equal the perimeter of the blue triangle, which implies the inequality between the means.
$$\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2}\geq a+b.$$

More visually, the green ellipse has the same focal points as the blue one, but intersects the red circle in 4 points (the tip and 3 reflections), while the blue does only in two. Hence the radii of the green ellipse has to be smaller or equal the radii of the blue ellipse, which also implies the inequality between the means.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Personally, I think "Surely the isosceles..." is just a different wording of the original problem.

Comment: @QuangHoan Take two ellipses with focal points at endpoint of diameter. It's obvious the blue one is bigger, because it _contains_ the red circle, while the green intersects it in 4 points.

Comment: another mysterious claim :p (again, personal view).

Comment: @QuangHoang darek is just using the fact if you fix the ends of a rope in two points, and try to stretch it by pulling a point in between in many ways, the that point will belong to an ellipse whose focal points are end points of the rope...

Comment: @VividD I know the definition of ellipse. It's just unclear why the major axis of an ellipse is bigger than that of the other. (Of course it's like that in the picture, but if you have to explain the picture, you would need to resource back to this QM-AM inequality).

Comment: @QuangHoang Both ellipses have the same focal points, yet the blue one intersects the circle only in two points (its shorter axis is equal to the diameter) while the green in 4 (the tip of the green triangle and its 3 reflections). Actually it is enough to consider the blue ellipse, because it encompasses the circle—tips of triangles with perimeter equal to the blue give the ellipse, but I thought with two ellipses it would be more visual.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}} \ge \frac{a + b}{2} $$

To prove, square and subtract numerator and denominator separately getting

$$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} - {(\frac{a + b}{2}})^2 = a b > 0.$$

(In a geometrical reasoning an algebraic process is inherent.. even in the Pythagoras thm).