# Geometric meaning of the inequality $\frac{x^n + y^n}{2} > \left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^n$ for positive and distinct $x$ and $y$, and $n>1$

Tags: geometry, inequality

What is the geometric meaning of the following inequality:
$$ \dfrac{x^n + y^n}{2} > \left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)^n$$
$$ x > 0, y > 0, x \neq y , n > 1$$

Comment: Do you want to know for which $(x,y)$ this is true?  It's not true for all $(x,y)$, for example if $x,y>0$ and $n>0$ then I think the inequality cannot hold.

Comment: [Here's a picture for $n=2$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1418353/409) Generalize.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: How so?  One example is $\frac{6^2+8^2}{2} = 50 > 49 = \left(\frac{6+8}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: If you'll excuse a nitpick, I think most people would call that an _inequality_ rather than an "expression". :)

Comment: @Blue: That's very pretty!

Answer (score 3):

The graph of the $n$th power function is strictly convex on the set of positive real numbers.

Comment: Succinct and precise.  +1  Well done!